# React dynamic comments content from axios not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, render

**See Zac's solution below**

This part of code is not rendering, can someone please help me. The comments react variable is an array and is set:

```
0: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
1: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
2: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
3: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
4: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
5: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
6: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
7: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
8: {comment: {…}, subcomments: Array(0)}
length: 9
```

Even though I'm using map, it's still not working and I'm stuck solving it for 5 hours already! I think I'm missign avery obvious and minor edit to the code do it start working!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
                <CommentsBlock>
                  {comments.map((c, i) =>
                      {return (<Comment key={i}>
                        Hello
                        <Nickname>{c.comment.author}</Nickname>
                        <Contents>{c.comment.content}</Contents>
                        <LowerCommentContainer>
                          <span>{c.comment.date}</span>
                          <span
                            onClick={() => {
                              setPrev(c.comment);
                            }}
                          >
                            reply
                          </span>
                        </LowerCommentContainer>
                      </Comment>
                      )}
                   )}

                  <ContentsInputTitle id="commenttitle" />
                  <ContentsInput id="commentcontent" />
                  <Confirm id="confirm">Post</Confirm>
                </CommentsBlock>
```

Comments in console:
[image: comments]

```html
useEffect(async () => {
    setComments([]);
    let i = 0;
    setLoaded(false);
    await article.commentsArr.forEach(async (c) => {
      const { data } = await axios({
        url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/getcomment",
        withCredentials: true,
        method: "POST",
        data: { comment: { _id: c } },
      });
      if (!comments.includes({ ...data })) {
        comments.push({ ...data });
      }
      console.log(comments);
      i++;
      if (i === article.commentsArr.length - 1) {
        setLoaded(true);
        console.log("RESULT", comments);
        document
          .querySelector("#confirm")
          .addEventListener("click", async () => {
            const data = await axios({
              url: vars.BACKENDURL + "/comment",
              withCredentials: true,
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                article: article,
                comment: {
                  title: document.querySelector("#commenttitle").value,
                  content: document.querySelector("#commentcontent").value,
                  prev: prev,
                },
              },
            });
          });
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: can you show the `console.log` of comments to make sure it has value

Comment: I've updated. But please don't pay attention to the left content on the page, the content that is not covered by devtools tab, because I have mobile and desktop versions in separate files, and only desktop is rendering dynamic content yet, so the comments on the mobile version are static. When rendering on desktop dynamic content, I dont see it, as I already explained

Comment: You are wrapping these comments elements with <CommentsBlock>, could you double-check if this component is expecting to get `children` in props and already rendering them?

Comment: It' a styled component (CommentsBlock), it's a div, there shouldn't be anything wrong with it, I hope. At least it used to render static content before

Comment: I'll update the Q rn, maybe there's something wrong with useEffect, can you please give it a look?

Comment: instead of `comments.push({ ...data });`,  try `setComments(current => [...current, { ...data }]);`

Comment: Oh, @Zac! Thank you so much! It's fantastic amazing, it's working! Please post comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use the setter handler from useState hook to update the state, in this case `setComments`, (ex. `setComments(newComments)`)

Second, referring to [React Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)
Note that:

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

so instead of `comments.push({ ...data });`, 
or `setComments([...comments, { ...data }]);`,

you need to use `setComments(current => [...current, { ...data }]);`